# WatchKit Map Directions

Tags: ios, mapkit, watchkit

Can you open directions in a WatchKit app on the Apple Watch the same way you can in a full iOS App?

I'm using this code and nothing happens, but I don't know if that's just because I'm in the simulator.

```
CLLocation *firstStopLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:firstPartialRoute.arrivalYCo.doubleValue longitude:firstPartialRoute.arrivalXCo.doubleValue];
MKPlacemark *firstStopPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:firstStopLocation.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:firstStopPlacemark];
[destination setName:firstPartialRoute.arrivalName];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(firstStopLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000);

NSDictionary *mapOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:region.center],
                            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:region.span],
                            MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking,
                            MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: @NO};

[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[destination] launchOptions:mapOptions];
```

Comment: did you ever find a way to open Maps within an Apple Watch app? I am at the same place you were and don't know if this feature is available or if it only works on iPhone.  I have a similar code setup as you for opening the Maps application, it says it responds to openMapsWithItems: launchOptions, but nothing happens when it is called.

Comment: No. I spoke to an Apple guy on the forum and they said you couldn't do it. This was before watchOS 2 though so things might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot quite do it the way you have demonstrated.

You need to switch over to using a [WKInterfaceMap](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceMap). You should read all the documentation to get a better understanding of the limitations. You won't be able to use `MapKit` objects to configure it and it's only a static map that you can place annotations on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WWDC parties app in this list, it has covered using WKInterfaceMap on WatchKit in detail - https://github.com/sanketfirodiya/sample-watchkit-apps